# How can I extract row entry width of Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm having difficulty extracting the width of a selected row on a Google Gantt chart. To further elaborate I need the width of the singular data row, which I can see in the code behind under the 'rect' tag however not sure how to properly call the syntax for width retrieval.

[ganttchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB1aU.png)

Comment: Do you mean, for instance in the first row, the width of the blue block? Do you mean the width of the element in pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, wait for the chart's `'ready'` event to fire.

then we can get the `<rect>` elements from the chart.
there will be other `<rect>` elements, besides those that represent a row.

such as the chart area, etc.
we can filter those out by fill color...

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  var rows = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
  var bars = [];
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(row) {
    switch (row.getAttribute('fill')) {
      case '#ffffff':
      case '#f5f5f5':
      case 'none':
        // ignore
        break;

      default:
        bars.push(row);
    }
  });

  if (bars.length > 0) {
    console.log(parseFloat(bars[0].getAttribute('width')));
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
     new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
     new Date(2014, 5, 21), new Date(2014, 8, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
     new Date(2014, 8, 21), new Date(2014, 11, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Winter', 'Winter 2014', 'winter',
     new Date(2014, 11, 21), new Date(2015, 2, 21), null, 100, null],
    ['2015Spring', 'Spring 2015', 'spring',
     new Date(2015, 2, 22), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 50, null],
    ['2015Summer', 'Summer 2015', 'summer',
     new Date(2015, 5, 21), new Date(2015, 8, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
     new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
     new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
    ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
    ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
    ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
    ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    gantt: {
      trackHeight: 30
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rows = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    var bars = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(row) {
      switch (row.getAttribute('fill')) {
        case '#ffffff':
        case '#f5f5f5':
        case 'none':
          // ignore
          break;

        default:
          bars.push(row);
      }
    });

    if (bars.length > 0) {
      console.log(parseFloat(bars[0].getAttribute('width')));
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);

  function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
    return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat I just had a chance to review this and appreciate your answer very much, this was cuasing me quite some grief and took a different apporach, however I will re-explore my previous solution. Essentially im trying to add custom function that allows the bars to be "draggable" which isn't currently supported on Google Gantts. Once again thanks for your response! :)